# Check store open hours - errors with compare a String and an int

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to write my first C# script. The script is for opening hours... My `if ((weekDay == sunday) && time > openingTime && closingTime < time)` line is spitting errors due to:

> CS0019  C# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

After looking at related answers on SO, I still haven't been able to get my code working.  I've tried converting the `string` into an `int`, this didn't work (unless I did something stupid)

```
var weekDay = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
var isOpen = "We are open!";
var isClosed = "We are closed";
var sunday = DayOfWeek.Sunday;


var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");

var openingTime = 08;
var closingTime = 16;


if ((weekDay == sunday) && time > openingTime && time < closingTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine(isClosed);
}
```

Comment: Your `time` variable is of type `string` - you cannot compare a `string` to an `int` (which both `openingTime` and `clostingTime` are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to evaluate against the current hour. Use the DateTime.Hour property instead, you cannot do the comparison between an int and a string.

```
var weekDay = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
var isOpen = "We are open!";
var isClosed = "We are closed";
var sunday = DayOfWeek.Sunday;


var time = DateTime.Now.Hour;

var openingTime = 8;
var closingTime = 16;


if ((weekDay == sunday) && time > openingTime && time < closingTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine(isClosed);
}
```

Comment: Your answer does stop the error, although the output is now 19. Not "We are closed". Any idea how to tackle that?

Comment: Problem on my end which is solved. This worked, thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) struct insted of string and use its properties like [`Hour`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour) to retrieve current hour.

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
if ((time.DayOfWeek == sunday) && time.Hour > openingTime && closingTime < time.Hour)
{
    Console.WriteLine(isClosed);
}
```

This is a more structured way to solve a problem then convert `DateTime` to `string` and then parse the `string` back to extract current hour.

Comment: `clsoingTime` is an `int`.  `int` does not have a property `Hour`.